# Action of $GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ on lower half plane of $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms, mobius-transformation, general-linear-group

I began reading about modular forms and I had a question. So, I know that $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is mapped to the upper half complex plane using a function. The way I see it, the reason we map it to the upper plane and not the lower plane is because of the following. Assume we have a matrix $g=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c &  d\\
\end{pmatrix}\in SL(2,R)$ and a point $z\in \mathbb{C}$ then

$$\text{Im } gz=\text{Im }\frac{az+b}{cz+d}=\frac{ad-bc(\text{Im }z)}{|cz+d|^2}$$
Since the determinant of $g$ is 1 and the denominator is positive, then for a positive $\text{Im }z$ it must be the case that the points are translated to the upper plane which is positive. What happens if we had $g\in GL(2,R)$? when the determinant is -1, does it get translated to the lower half-plane?

FYI. I'm an undergrad so I'll probably have a hard time understanding a grad-level explanation.

Comment: Consider $g=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @KentaS ok. How do I connect that to my question? If we have $a=-1$ then does that mean we have Im(z)<0? or am I missing something you're saying?

Comment: $\Im( gz) = \det(g)\frac{\Im(z)}{|cz+d|^2}$ so yes obviously for $\Im(z) >0$ then $gz$ is in the upper halfplane iff $\det g > 0$ otherwise it is in the lower half plane. The title of your question is weird.

Comment: @reuns Ow, that makes sense. Also, I understand what you meant by the title so I did change it.

Comment: There are multiple issues with this question, starting with the sentence "So, I know that (2,ℤ) is mapped to the upper half complex plane using a function." What you really meant to say here is that if $Im(z)>0$ and $SL(2,{\mathbb Z})$ acts on the extended complex plane in the standard fashion, then $Im(g(z))>0$ for all $z$ in the upper half-plane.  Next issue is with the question "What happens if we had ∈(2,)?" Next issue  "when the determinant is -1, does it get translated to the lower half-plane?": What is "it" here? I assume, it is $g$. What do you mean by "get translated"?...